# Error in installation of Hive 2.1.0 on Hadoop 2.7.2 - Pseudo distributed mode

Tags: hive, slf4j, hadoop-2.7.2

I followed Apache Hadoop installation links and could install the same along with PIG. They all are working fine.

Following is the configuration:
Hadoop: 2.7.2
Hive: 2.1.0
Machine: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit
Java: Version 9

Now I tried to install Apache Hive 2.1.0 according to this link [https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Installation#AdminManualInstallation-InstallingfromaTarball].

... and started test execution of Hive CLI but everytime it throws following error and exits.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hive/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader (in module: java.base) cannot be cast to java.net.URLClassLoader (in module: java.base)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init> (SessionState.java:374)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.<init>(SessionState.java:350)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliSessionState.<init>(CliSessionState.java:60)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:663)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(java.base@9-ea/Native Method)
at jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(java.base@9-ea/DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.base@9-ea/Method.java:533)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

..But there is a catch. If I invoke Beeline CLI then it works fine.

Could you please help :
a. Are the Beeline CLI and Hive CLI same or any specific difference?
b. Help to install/configure Hive on my machine

Answer (score 0):

A : Beeline CLI VS Hive CLI  https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.4.2/bk_dataintegration/content/beeline-vs-hive-cli.html

B : According to :
http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/talks/prepare-for-jdk9-j1-2015.pdf

Java 9 Uses no longer uses java.net.URLClassLoader.

However, I was able to solve the issue by pointing Hive to JDK8.

** I have only begun using HIVE/HADOOP... Perhaps someone could proved a better explanation or a workaround so that we are able to use JDK9...